# Sending custom response when get fails with https native module and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express application and within it, an HTTP GET request to an API.
It works well when there's no error, but when something fails I would like to send a custom response to the client-side through Express:

```
const https = require('https');

// more code: init express, middlewares, etc

app.get('/my-endpoint', async (req, res) => {

  https.get('https://my-api.com', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      res.send({ data: JSON.parse(data) })
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    res.send({ data: 'Something went wrong' })
  });

});
```

The thing is that always sends what `res.send({ data: JSON.parse(data) })` resolves to, which is an array of objects when it works, or an empty object `{}` when it does not. I cannot make work the part of sending `'Something went wrong'` if the request fails.

I will appreciate the help. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when you are calling `https://my-api.com`, server response is 200 and returns HTML.

Error happens in `JSON.parse(data)` and it will not get to `on("error", ...)` part.

You can catch this error like this:

```
resp.on("end", () => {
  try {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    res.send({ data: JSON.parse(data) });
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ data: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

otherwise your code works and it returns `{ data: 'Something went wrong' }` on non 200 response